# Is there a way to use "assert_called_with" that only checks specific word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to use `assert_called_with` to assert the argument that is passed to the mocked object. There is only one argument of that function but the argument is very large.
`{"A":{"B": {"C" : {"D": {"key": "keyword", "any": "aaa", "anything": "bbbb"}}}}`

I only care about `"key": "keyword"` exists and do not care about other stuff, is there a way to do so?

Comment: You could use `assert_called_once`, and then check `call_args.kwargs` (or `call_args.args` if you don't use keyword agruments). If this is a nested dict you may have to recursively go through the dict.

Comment: @MrBeanBremenm, thanks, actually this function is called twice, and any of them contains {"key": "keyword"} which is what I want to assert, is there a way?

Comment: In this case you can use `call_args_list`. Each entry in the list contains the args for a call, so you have to iterate through the list.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen is it possible to assert {"key": "keyword"} exists in the argument with this way? I do not want to assert the whole argument because it is too large (there is only one argument which is a big dictionary)

Comment: Not directly, if this is a nested dictionary. You have to traverse the dictionary and check for your key/value at each level. It depends on how flexible the argument structure actually is.

Comment: I added it as an answer, as it may not be completely straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your function has one argument, that is a nested dictionary and shall on some level contain the specific key/value pair, you have to iterate over that dictionary manually using some function.

You get the arguments of all calls of your mocked function from `call_args_list`. Each entry contains a tuple with the list of positional arguments and the keyword arguments, e.g. `call_args_list[0][0][0]` contains the first positional argument of the first call.

Assuming that your tested function have always exactly one arguments, that is called as a positional argument, you can do something like this:

```py
def dict_contains_key_value(arg, key, value):
    if not isinstance(arg, dict):
        return False
    for k, v in arg.items():
        if k == key and v == value:
            return True
        if dict_contains_key_value(v, key, value):
            return True
    return False


@mock.patch("my_module.sut")
def test_called_arg(mocked):
    caller()  # the function that calls `sut()` several times
    mocked.assert_called()
    assert any(dict_contains_key_value(args[0][0], "key", "keyword")
               for args in mocked.call_args_list)
```

A few notes:

- if you are not sure that the function has always an argument, you have to add a check (e.g. for `args[0]`)
- if the argument can also be called as a keyword argument, you have to expand the check (`args[1]` would give you the dictionary of keyword arguments)
- the function `dict_contains_key_value` can be optimized and extended if needed, this is just a simple example